# Accessing ApplicationUser for foreign key without reference to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have divided my ASP.NET MVC 5 project into two distinct projects/assemblies:

- MyProject.Entities

and

- MyProject.Web

Where `.Entities` contains my business/domain logic (basically model classes for my custom data objects) and `.Web` contains the actual ASP.NET MVC framework and web infrastructure.

I am basing this design off of Scott Allen's excellent ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamentals course where he explains how it separates the business logic from the web infrastructure.

However I've run into a problem which Scott only briefly addresses: accessing `ApplicationUser` in my `.Entities` classes.

I want my data entity's table to contain a foreign key pointing to a specific `ApplicationUser` for each entry. But because `ApplicationUser` inherits from `IdentityUser`, I would need a reference to `AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`.

Scott says that "isn't going to work for a lot of people", and is "rather distasteful". He says that I would have to implement my own `UserStore` or `UserManager` to utilize it.

I believe that is vastly overkill for simply wanting to be able to foreign key `ApplicationUser` in a few tables.

I can get the foreign key column in question into my data table by creating a navigational property in the `ApplicationUser` class in `IdentityModel` like so:

```
using MyProject.Entities;

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

and then doing a simple Entity Framework migration. However, I can't explicitly access the user through my object.

So:

1. Why would it be "distasteful" to reference Entity Framework in my business/domain layer, and
2. How can I get a foreign key reference declared in that layer to `ApplicationUser` where I need it?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and I am just moving my Entities out of that separate assembly and into the main assembly. I have only 1 entity as it's a really simple application, so it's not really a good answer to your question. For something that is meant to make life easier, Entity Framework sure comes with some frustrations. I have had no such frustrations with ORMs like PetaPoco.